# macOS Mojave - NSReadPixel is not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimage, nsimageview, macos-mojave

I have subclassed `NSImageView` to override `mouseDown` method to get the colour of clicked point and so far it was working fine on all OS versions (up to 10.13.x) but on 10.14 this doesn't seems to be working and I am always getting null colour when using `NSReadPixel`. Below is my code of `mouseDown` method.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
if(!self.image)
    return;
NSPoint clickedPoint = theEvent.locationInWindow;
NSPoint pointInDocumentView = [self convertPoint:clickedPoint fromView:nil];
[self lockFocus];
NSColor* colorAtClickedPoint = NSReadPixel(pointInDocumentView);
[self unlockFocus];
if(colorAtClickedPoint){
    if(self.delegate){
       [self.delegate colourCodeDidChange:colorAtClickedPoint];
    }
}
```

}

Please help.

Comment: What is NSReadPixal?

Comment: Please see this - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1473606-nsreadpixel?language=objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is deprecated in 10.14. You may use other methods like the following. Hope you have no problem with the answer.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
            if(!self.image)
                return;
            NSPoint clickedPoint = theEvent.locationInWindow;

            NSPoint pointInDocumentView = [self convertPoint:clickedPoint fromView:nil];
            NSBitmapImageRep * bitmapImageRep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
            [self cacheDisplayInRect:self.bounds toBitmapImageRep:bitmapImageRep];
            [self lockFocus];
              NSColor* colorAtClickedPoint  =  [bitmapImageRep colorAtX:pointInDocumentView.x y:pointInDocumentView.y];

            [self unlockFocus];
            if(colorAtClickedPoint){
                if(self.delegate){
                    [self.delegate colourCodeDidChange:colorAtClickedPoint];
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yes looks like that is the correct now after 10.14. Agree that NSReadPixel is deprecated but even deprecated methods works upto a time and it's just deprecated with 10.14 not even 10.13. This is no way good by Apple.